# Is $(x+y)^{p_1+p_2} \leq C x^{p_1} y^{p_2}$ for some constant $C>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Let $x, y>0, p_1>0$ and $p_2<0.$

> Can we say that $$(x+y)^{p_1+p_2} \leq C x^{p_1} y^{p_2}$$ for some constant $C>0$?

Comment: Yes, certainly – for $C\ge\frac{(x+y)^{p_1+p_2}}{x^{p_1}y^{p_2}}$. You seem to be missing some universal quantifiers.

Answer (score 2):

For $x\rightarrow0^+$ the right side is closed to $0^+$ for any $C>0$, but the left side is positive,  which gives that we can not say this.